# React current user Context or Composition

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I'm trying to understand the best practice use-cases of React Context API vs the standard Composition pattern.

One of the edge-cases, in my opinion, would be an authenticated user that the App uses its data (e.g. `User: {name: string, pass: string, posts: Array<>, ...}`) throughout the code (in different components).

I tried deciphering what React Docs has to say about it, but it's kinda awkward because it seem to be sort of self-contradictory.

In the beginning the Docs gives a couple of examples for Context usage:

> Context is designed to share data that can be considered “global” for a tree of React components, such as the **current authenticated user**, theme, or preferred language.

But then it goes to say that in many cases Composition would be enough, and the given example is about a current user:

> For example, consider a Page component that passes a **`user`** and `avatarSize` prop several levels down so that deeply nested `Link` and `Avatar` components can read it... One way to solve this issue **without context** is to pass down the Avatar component itself so that the intermediate components don’t need to know about the `user` or `avatarSize` props

So essentially after saying that Context would be good for user data handling, the Docs gives an example using Composition.

I'm not trying to nit-pick on, or mock the Docs, definitely not my intent. What I'm trying to understand is, since obviously both ways are applicable, what is the best practice for user data handling throughout the App? Are there any considerations I should take when choosing between those two methods, aside from comfortability? I see that in the Docs it says about Context:

> Apply it sparingly because it makes component reuse more difficult

How so, especially in this case? I can understand it in cases where you don't know what data your component would require (and hence the use of `props.children`), but that isn't such a case.

Comment: It makes component reuse more difficult because components then depend on a `Context`, and cannot be reused without that context. The point of the second doc paragraph is that depending on the app you may not need to expose global properties via a context. "Best practice" depends on the app.

Comment: @DaveNewton isn't it just adding `useContext` whenever the `Context` use needed? And "cannot be reused without that context" - meaning once I `Provide` a context I *must* `use` it in every component in the tree? Sounds weird. And I get that best practice is case-dependent, but user data is a very general concept no? Isn't there sort of commonly accepted implementation to it?

Comment: You only need to use it where it's needed. But once it's used that component can no longer work without it. Yes, users are a general concept--the *implementation* of that general concept may or may not benefit from a context. It depends on the app.

Comment: @DaveNewton well, it feels like it's the same as saying that adding a new prop requirement makes the component more difficult to use (especially with ts). And can you give me an example where it may and may not benefit from using Context?

Comment: Adding a new prop, particularly in TS, is self-contained, though. A context is an *internal* detail of a component. A prop is an *external* detail.

Comment: @DaveNewton oh I understand, the idea is that it's more difficult to *understand* how to use the component (i.e. mostly by different developers, or by future *you*), not that the component itself is more difficult to reuse generally?

Comment: It's more difficult to reuse *generally* because of the internal detail. Inside a *single app* it's not any more difficult (assuming the context is always "above" the component in question) and arguably easier.

Comment: @DaveNewton yes that's what I meant, perhaps misused "generally" (by generally I meant in theory, not in practical case of a team with multiple devs working on the same codebase). Anyways thank you for the response.